# Howe hide and visible img in React?

Tags: reactjs

Add button and image. When you click on the button, hide the image; when you click again, show.

```
 <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2460/2460099.svg" />
  <button onClick={this.btn}>Count</button>
```

Comment: can you show code inside this.btn?

Answer (score 2):

you can maintain a state for the same, like

```
{this.state.isImageVisible?<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2460/2460099.svg" />:<div></div>}   

      <button onClick={this.btn}>Count</button>
```

and on click of button ,

do this

```
btn =() => {

this.setState({isImageVisible:!this.state.isImageVisible});


}
```

Hope it helps